# Sql Parameter default values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Noob question... I've just come across an input parameter like this:

```
@Id INT NULL
```

Is this just saying it's nullable? Or is it not the same as below. What's the difference?

```
@Id INT = NULL
```

Comment: The first is declaring the variable as an integer that is nullable but not setting a value.  The second is simultaneously declaring and setting the variable.

Comment: @user1443098 Cheers, so am I correct in thinking if a Null value is passed in then they both have the same result?

Comment: yup.  the difference is that, in a parameter list, if you don't give it a default (like null), it must be specified when it is called.  so using the second option, the caller could omit that parameter, using the first they can't

Comment: @user1443098 ok thanks, happy to accept this as an answer

Comment: All variables are NULLable... the "= NULL" is completely redundant and unnecessary. At best, it tells the next person who has to look at the code that this was intentionally defaulted to NULL by the original developer.... Edit... Just noticed the word parameter (indicating stored procedure not ad-hoc sql)... In that case, it does allow the parameter to go unfilled when executing the proc as user1443098 mentioned...

Comment: @JasonA.Long The procedure I'm looking at uses coalesce to update the rows if not null or leave be, so I can see why it was initially declared as NULL